# Использование метода одного класса в другом

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, методы

Я не могу разобраться, как вызвать метод одного класса в другом.

Предположим, есть такой код:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        #code
    
    def method(self):
        #code


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        #code

    def method2(self):
        A().method()
```

Я пробовал уже и `A().method()`, и `self.method()`, но ничего не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

никак :)

вернее способов 2

1. класс `A` у вас находится внутри класса `B` как член класса

например так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self):
        pass


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

    def method2(self):
        self.a.method()


elem = B()
elem.method2()
```

2. класс `B` является наследником класса `A`

например так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method2(self):
        self.method()


elem = B()
elem.method2()
```

подозреваю, что вам нужен второй случай

Comment: Как раз таки 2 случай мне не подходит, попробую первый, спасибо

Comment: спасибо, помог 1 способ

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def method(self):
        print(f'class A: def method(self): Hello') #


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.a = A()

    def method2(self):
        self.a.method()

a = A()
b = B()
b.method2()
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Comment: @zikker пожалуйста. Если какой-то из ответов помог вам, то не забудьте пометить его как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour